# function of a required file in lua doesn't seem to be called

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to use `require` keyword in LUA to include a file with functions, since I am new to LUA firstly I tried a simple print function:

globalfunctions.lua

```
local globalfunctions = {}

function printSomething()
    print("OOOK")
end

return globalfunctions
```

then I tried to call this function writing:

```
local m = require "globalfunctions"
m.printSomething()
```

but an error occurred saying **"attempt to call field printSomething (nil value)"** 
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you declare a function but don't add it to your module.

To actually store the function in the module returned by `require`, you need to add it to the table you return at the end of your module.

```
globalfunctions.printSomething = printSomething
```

Note that globalfunctions is a deceiving name choice, since a) it's a local variable itself b) the functions it will contain will not be global either, they are contained by your module

Secondly: Ideally, to make your module behave as most people expect it, you would make the function local as to not pollute the global namespace (potentially overriding an existing variable).

Comment: Cleaner: function globalfunctions.printSomething() ... end

Answer (score 1):

You made global functions a local value, meaning it can only operate locally, try changing local to global.

Comment: This is not the issue here. It's perfect as local variable (though the name is a tad confusing), as it is returned at the end of the module. For the true cause, take a look at my answer.